# Can ば conditional form be interpreted as a conjunction?

Tags: conditionals, particle-も

I was just introduced a new grammar point, the も~も construction as shown on https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/. I understand the main function of も and how it is the inclusionary particle and I can follow along with most of the examples for the grammar point that the site provides, but I can't make out how sentences with ば (I've only known the form to be the conditional. Haven't done grammar lookups in j-j dictionaries) are working.

One of the samples sentences provided is

```
彼は親戚でもなければ友達でもない。
```

and the english interpretation is "He is neither a relative nor a friend." My question is how does なければ, what I would think would be the ば conditional of ない, work here? Literal English translations aren't doing me much good here if I try and translate this taking ば as the conditional. Can someone help me understand how this is working?

Comment: Oddly, couldn’t find a relevant 明鏡 entry.

Comment: @Darius, 明鏡、「ば」〘接助〙❾の、"《「AもすればBもする」の形で》同類の事柄を並べて述べる。…もするし…もする。…でもあり…でもある。「雨もふれば風も吹く」「職**もなければ**家**もない** 」" ←これじゃないかな？

Comment: Nice, missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better translation might be "Whilst he is not a relative, neither is he a friend."